# What is "keyboard hook timeout value" and should it be changed to accommodate VMWare?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware

I'm running Windows 10 natively and attempting to get a VMWare VM going.  I'm currently making an Ubuntu 14.04 VM but this same message seems to appear even if I start a different VM:

[image]

I'll type the text out here so a search engine can find this post:

> The keyboard hook timeout value is not set to the value recommended by
>   VMWare Workstation.  This can cause keystrokes to be lost when the
>   host is under stress.  We recommend that you allow this application to
>   update the value.  Once this value is updated, you must log out and
>   log in again in order to have the value take effect.

Can somebody explain what a "keyboard hook timeout value" is, and reasoning to choose either "OK" or "Cancel"?

So far I've been choosing "Cancel" since my native Windows 10 install is working well and I'm hesitant to change an operating system setting, which this text seems to apply choosing "OK" would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware products for Windows install a low-level keyboard hook so that when the VM is "grabbed", it can intercept the keyboard events and send them to the guest OS without the events going to some other application on the host.

They keyboard hook timeout is the amount of time that the hook has to process the keyboard event.  The prompt is requesting that you allow the product to automatically increase the keyboard hook timeout so that if the host is heavily loaded, keyboard events won't be dropped.

My understanding is that increasing the timeout isn't that important anymore and is mostly vestigial.  Sadly, the prompt is also broken (the only way to get VMware Workstation to stop asking you is to click OK).

You also can consult [the MSDN documentation for the OS setting (LowLevelHooksTimeout)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx).